# Representatives for the action on an unknown set of matrices by an unknown modular subgroup

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, modular-group

Let $\Gamma$ be the modular group and $\mathcal M_n$ the set of all primitive matrices with determinant $n\geq1$. Recall that a primitive matrix has relatively prime entries.

The modular group $\Gamma$ acts on the set $\mathcal M _n$ from the left. The representatives of the orbits of this action can be chosen as

$$S(n)=\bigg \lbrace \begin{pmatrix}r &s\\0&t\end{pmatrix}:r>0,rt=n,(r,s,t)=1,0\leq s<t\bigg\rbrace.$$

One encounters this, for example, when studying the modular equation $\Phi_n(X,X)$. Cf. [Zagier, p. 68](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/978-3-540-74119-0_1/fulltext.pdf).

Now consider a generalization of $S(n)$, namely

$$\mathcal{S}\left(n,d\right)=\bigg\lbrace \begin{pmatrix}r &s\\0&t\end{pmatrix}: r>0,rt=n,(r,t,s)=1,d \mid s, 0 \leq s < dt\bigg\rbrace.$$

These sets arise from the study of modular functions for certain subgroups of $\Gamma$ and their transformation equations.

**My question is this: is there some set of matrices $\mathcal M_{n,d}$ and a subgroup $\Gamma_{n,d}\subset\Gamma$ such that $S(n,d)$ is a set of representatives for the orbits of the left action $\Gamma_{n,d}\backslash\mathcal M_n$?**

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a trivial example: take
$$
\mathcal{M}_{n,d} = \left\{ 
\begin{pmatrix}
r & s \\
0 & t
\end{pmatrix} ~:~ rt = n, d \mid s,~ (r,t,n)=1
\right\}
$$
and the subgroup
$$
\Gamma_{n,d} = \left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
0 & c
\end{pmatrix}~:~ ac = 1,~d\mid b
\right\} ~\subset~ \Gamma.
$$
Another idea is to write $\mathcal{S}(n,d)$ as the quotient
$$\mathcal{S}(n,d) = g\Gamma g^{-1}~\backslash~ g\mathcal{M}_n g^{-1}$$
for $$g =\begin{pmatrix} d & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$
but $g\Gamma g^{-1}$ is not a subgroup of $\Gamma$.

Comment: This seems somewhat artificial. I am seeking a more natural group. But I admit that the question is stated rather vaguely. I will try to improve it.